# Transparently accept events

Tags: c++, qt

I have two widgets, **A** and **B**. **B** is directly on top of **A** using a Grid Layout.

```
+------------------------
| QGraphicsView A
|
|   +--------------------
|   |QGraphicsView B
|   |
|   |
|   |
```

**A** needs to accept all mouse events (move, press, release, etc.). **B** needs to transparently accept only mouse move. How can I get **B** to accept only mouse move and then pass all other events (including mouse move) to **A** (without knowing anything about A)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is for the parent to install an EventFilter on the child and do the logic of which events you want to swallow or pass through.

Take a look here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter